# how to test ajax page

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, testing

I've create a codeigniter app that includes a page with some ajax. 
I'm trying to prove to myself that the ajax page is in fact working.  That is, that only one section of my page is being updated, and the rest stays as is.

Here's my code in the controller: 
(index is the method that is called on initial page load.  index2() is called when the refresh button is clicked)

```
       public function index()
       {
           $this->load->model('locations_model');
           $data['clienthistory'] = $this->locations_model->get_locations();
           $data['main_content'] = 'dashboard';
           $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
       }


       public function index2()
       {
          $this->load->model('locations_model');
          $data['clienthistory'] = $this->locations_model->get_locations();
          return json_encode($data['clienthistory']);                                                                     
       }
```

And here is my view:

```
 <h2>timer test</h2>
    <?php echo now();?>

<h2>Latest Client Status</h2>
            <?php echo form_open('Dashboard/index');          
            echo form_submit('submit', 'Refresh Client Data', 'id="clientsubmit" class="btn-primary"');
            ?>
      <div class="row-fluid">
             <div class="span12" id="ajaxcontainer">
               <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                 <tr>
                   <th>IP</th>                                                                                                          
                   <th>Name</th>                                                                           
                   <th>Last Updated</th>
                 </tr>
                 </thead>
                <tbody>
               <?php foreach ($clienthistory as $histitem): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $histitem['network'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $histitem['name'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $histitem['lastupdated'] ?></td>
                    </tr>
               <?php endforeach ?>

                </tbody>
               </table>
       </div>

     <?php echo form_close();  ?>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#clientsubmit').click(function() {                   
               $.ajax({                                
                    url:"<?php echo site_url('Dashboard/index2'); ?>",
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'html'
                    success: function(returnDataFromController) {
                          $('#ajaxcontainer').html(returnDataFromController)
                    }
                  });

       return false;      
     });
    </script>
```

The idea is to display the current time on the page, in an area that is not supposed to be updated by my ajax call.  But when I click on my refresh button, in addition to updating the table data, the time is being updated too. 
I'm not sure I understand why this is happening. any help would be appreciated.  apologize in advance for the remedial questions - just new to codeigniter and to ajax.
thanks.

Comment: your refresh button is a `submit` so it will refresh the page, you need to change it to, for instance `button` and append a action to it with `JS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is a `submit` so it will refresh the page when clicked.

You need to change it to something else, like `<a></a>` and append a action to it, something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="clientsubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Refresh Client Data</a>
```

Since you are using twitter bootstrap, the link won't mess with your layout adding a `btn` to it's class.

Without the `submit` button, your page won't be refreshed and your date function will be intact.

And just for precaution, disable that link/button when clicked until the request is returned.

```
$('#clientsubmit').click(function() {
$(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
...
$('#ajaxcontainer').html(returnDataFromController);
$(this).removeAttr("disabled");
...
```

And on your ajax call you will just update the `ajaxcontainer` element.

Hope it helps.

Comment: unfortunately, when i change it to an anchor, it no longer triggers the click function...

Comment: it makes no sense, can you check your chrome with CTRL+SHIFT+j and see if there is any messages?

Comment: daniel, you were right. there was another problem.  i was missing a comma after my dataType in the ajax call.  but after fixing that syntax problem, it looks like my ajax is not working.  i tried adding an echo statement in my index3() method... and its not being executed.

Comment: so now the click event was called?

Comment: yes, click event is called.  But i think index3() is failing.  I added an echo right at the start of index3().  then it does the select statement against the database.  I added "console.log(returnDataFromController);" to my ajax function. and in the console, i see my echo statement... and only the echo.  not any data.

Comment: i changed my logic to "echo" my json data instead of "return" in the controller.  now in the console, i see the latest data being returned, but the data on the page is not updated.

Comment: I think you have to `echo` the json result, not `return`

Comment: yep.  i did change that and now i can see that the data is being sent because in the console, i can see the latest values.  but for some reason, the <div> is not being refreshed...???

Comment: on your success function add a alert: `success: function(returnDataFromController) {
     alert($('#ajaxcontainer'));
                    }` to see if the result is returned correctly.

Comment: daniel, so i must have not refreshed properly or something.  but now i've got the data coming back!  woo hoo! but you know what?  i forgot something really obvious.  the data being returned is an array... i'm just dumping it to the screen instead of looping through it and creating a proper html table.  i guess i would do that in the ajax function right?

Comment: yes, correct and I think your `ajaxcontainer` id should be a `<span>` inside your `<tbody>` so you don't need to recreated the table headers which will be the same on every request ;)

Comment: in my opinion, you should do that loop, generating the table body on your class and returning it as you need, not using `json`, simply `html` instead

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12460/discussion-between-dot-and-daniel)